Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api in appsync invoking restapi
I am using restapi as a resolver for appsync in aws.
Api gateway has the following resource policy

Edit

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "execute-api:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<region>:<accnumber>:<api id>/*/*/*"
    }
  ]
}

On the appsync side, I am using following config for invoking api

The role has following trusted policy and admin permission
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

When i run graphql query, I get following error  Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. Whole message as follows -
"result": {
            "headers": {
                "Content-Length": "77",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Date": "Sat, 31 Aug 2024 03:26:33 GMT",
                "Via": "1.1 1c83c89ce5e3ed0b002e3445f36e0a00.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
                "x-amz-apigw-id": "dWsIhEZxIAMEbEA=",
                "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "deWxKeOd26E8LZnd1eRlZiBr8uETWh-60CbrcAgsgci6k11m-hQW7g==",
                "X-Amz-Cf-Pop": "IAD61-P5",
                "x-amzn-ErrorType": "InvalidSignatureException",
                "x-amzn-RequestId": "b3824bf8-ee23-4737-a728-bcb887fdb126",
                "X-Cache": "Error from cloudfront"
            },
            "statusCode": 403,
            "body": "{\"message\":\"Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. \"}"
        },

